# Git difftool - Show diff UI even if there are no changes

Tags: git, git-extensions

Currently when using `git difftool`, the UI won't open if there were no changes for a file.

Is there a way to make it open the difftool even if there were no changes?

Relevant [Git-Extensions issue](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1842).

Comment: I had this need and got stumped as well.  This capability would be useful, for example, if you wanted to edit a clean file in your external diff tool.  @VitalyB, if you discover a solution, please return here and answer it!